# what does ecl stand for?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys! This might be a silly question, but I'm new to ROS. What does ecl actually stand for? I have been unable to find it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368926/what-does-ecl-stand-for?/) by [Babra](https://answers.ros.org/users/67160/babra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-05**:
[wiki/ecl](http://wiki.ros.org/ecl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Embedded Control Libraries

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Babra](https://answers.ros.org/users/67160/babra/) on 2021-01-05**:
Thank you so much! It is greatly appreciated!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-01-05**:
@Babra please use the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept the answer so @stevemacenski get the credit and others know that your answer has a solution.